# Saving layer to map document and not layer file?

Tags: arcpy, definition-query

I'm trying to write a python script that runs a definition query. I'm having a problem with saving the query directly to a layer in a map document and not as its own layer file. Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import os
import datetime

#getting the right layer to modify
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"U:\FullPath.mxd")
layerName = "BuildingFootprintsCopy"
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
print dataFrame
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, layerName)
print layers
layerFromMap = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, layerName, dataFrame)[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame, layerFromMap, "AUTO_ARRANGE")

#Definition Query
date2 = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=730)
print date2

dQueryVar1 = 'TOTAL_NUMB_FLOORS = ' + "2"
dQueryVar2 = "DATE_BUILT >=" + " date " + "'" + str(date2) + "'"
layerFromMap.definitionQuery = dQueryVar1 + " AND " + dQueryVar2
layerFromMap.save(mxd) #This is the line that throws the error.


print "finished"
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\TestDefinitionQueryWithDate.py", line 35, in <module>
    layerFromMap.save(mxd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
TypeError: save() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I've tried:

```
layerFromMap.save(r"U:\FullPath.mxd")
```

That returns the exact error. I'm not sure why I'm passing 2 arguments instead of 1. I've also tried :

```
layerFromMap.save()
```

That returns an error for not specifying a path.

How can I save my layer as the layer in the mxd I ran the definition query on and not as its own path? Can I save it in such a way that there is one layer with all of the data it originally contained with the definition Query on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few remarks:

1. `mxd.save()` is the way to go.  When you add a layer to/modify an existing layer in an mxd, you save the mxd, not the layer. It's like adding something (picture/text/etc) to a word doc, you save the word doc, not the "something"...
2. In most cases you can use `dataFrame = mxd.activeDataFrame` instead of listing the data frames (unless there's multiple data frames in the mxd and you need a specific one).
3. You don't need to add the layer, just modify it in place (unless you want to duplicate it on purpose).

An example:

```
import arcpy
import os
import datetime

#getting the right layer to modify
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"U:\FullPath.mxd")
layerName = "BuildingFootprintsCopy"
dataFrame = mxd.activeDataFrame
layerFromMap = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, layerName, dataFrame)[0]

#Definition Query
date2 = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=730)
print date2

dQueryVar1 = 'TOTAL_NUMB_FLOORS = ' + "2"
dQueryVar2 = "DATE_BUILT >=" + " date " + "'" + str(date2) + "'"
layerFromMap.definitionQuery = dQueryVar1 + " AND " + dQueryVar2

mxd.save()
```

Comment: #2 I did not know, I'll have to make use of that!

Comment: That was a good answer. I'll think about what my code is actually doing more in the future. I did not realize that There was no reason to add a new layer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
layerFromMap.save(mxd)
```

just do:

```
mxd.save()
```

It will save every layer in your MapDocument to that MXD and will retain any definition queries that you have applied to their Properties.